# ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

> pig -param CURR_TS=`date "+%F %H:%M:%S"` -f pig_script.pig

After running this i am getting below Error -

**ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: 04:36:33**

---

**I know the problem is with ":" colon, but what I want is to use same timestamp format passed by param into pig, so that i can use of it to perform certain operation.**

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Try declaring the variable to the

```
export dateFormat=`date "+%F %H:%M:%S"`
```

And then run pig script by passing the param value.

```
pig -x local -f read_test_data3.pig -param CURR_TS=$dateFormat
```

2) Or Else pass the expression in  pig command as below :

```
pig -x local -f read_test_data3.pig -param CURR_TS=`date "+%F %H:%M:%S"`
```